# Elixir / SQL - Converting a list to lower case before performing a query using it

Tags: sql, elixir, ecto

I'm attempting to search my database for all users with an e-mail contained in a given list of e-mails, irrelevant of case. My code is:

```
  def get_user_ids_from_emails(emails) do
    emails = Enum.map(emails, fn email -> String.downcase(email) end)

    from(
      u in User,
      where:
        fragment(
          "LOWER(?) IN ?",
          u.email,
          ^emails
        ),
      select: u.id
    )
  end
```

When I try and execute this i receive

```
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42601 (syntax_error) syntax error at or near "$1"
     
         query: SELECT u0."id" FROM "user" AS u0 WHERE (LOWER(u0."email") IN $1)
```

Is this the right approach? And if so how can I format the list so that it's accepted by SQL?

Comment: isn't parenthesis missing in your query? `"LOWER(?) IN (?)"`

Comment: Receiving the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [Elixir Forum](https://elixirforum.com/t/ecto-performing-a-case-insensitive-search-with-a-list/44090), need to exclude the list from the fragment:

```
def get_user_ids_from_emails(emails) do
  emails = Enum.map(emails, fn email -> String.downcase(email) end)

  from(
    u in User,
    where:
      fragment("LOWER(?)", u.email) in ^emails,
    select: u.id
  )
end
```